# Python: avoiding conflict of NumPy's unittest.py with local unittest.py

Tags: python, numpy

Has anyone else encountered the situation where they have written unit tests for their code into a file named unittest.py, and found it to conflict with NumPy's unittest.py module?  In other words, if I write this to unittest.py in a local directory:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "pre-import"
    #import numpy
    print "post-import"
```

Then (no surprises here):

```
% python unittest.py
pre-import
post-import
```

But if I do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "pre-import"
    import numpy
    print "post-import"
```

I get:

```
% python unittest.py
pre-import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
ImportError: cannot import name TestCase
```

Subsequently, iPython fails to load:

```
% ipython
WARNING: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 402, in launch_new_instance
    app.initialize()
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 312, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 332, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir)
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 318, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 183, in __init__
    user_module=user_module, custom_exceptions=custom_exceptions
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 478, in __init__
    self.init_reload_doctest()
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 662, in init_reload_doctest
    doctest_reload()
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/doctestreload.py", line 72, in doctest_reload
    import doctest
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 2118, in <module>
    class DocTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Interestingly, if I move the import statement outside of the `"if __name__"` suite, e.g.,

```
print "pre-import"
import numpy
print "post-import"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

I get:

```
% python unittest.py
pre-import
pre-import
post-import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/home/jbbrown/local_bin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
ImportError: cannot import name TestCase
```

Of course it is trivial to change the name of the file containing my unit tests and avoid this, but I wonder if anyone else encountered this and thought of an elegant workaround that doesn't include renaming their unit test file?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to [absolute imports](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) by default on Python versions newer than 2.7:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "pre-import"
    import numpy
    print "post-import"
```